# Why I'm getting wrong filter result?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to get the Product entity with Id = 5002. Each Product has a list of Orders. So that I'm filtering the Orders to get only Orders with Total greatter 10.00 but the EF returns me the full list.

```
using (var context = new SuperMarketContext())
{
    var product = context.Product
        .Include(p => p.Orders)
        .Where(p => p.Id == 5002)
        .First();

    context.Entry(product)
        .Collection(p => p.Orders)
        .Query()
        .Where(o => o.Total > 10)
        .Load();

    foreach (var item in product.Orders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Like I said it's bring me all Orders instad just ones gretters than 10. Why it's  happening ?

EF Core 1.1.2

.Net Framework 4.6.1

Comment: I think you need to remove `.Include(p => p.Orders)`. Doesn't that bring in all orders?

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 It does and he should then query the orders on the product to get the ones with totals of > 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have a list of orders for that product why query the database again?

Fixed to your code:

```
using (var context = new SuperMarketContext())
{
    var product = context.Product
        .Include(p => p.Orders)
        .Where(p => p.Id == 5002)
        .First();

    var filteredOrders = context.Entry(product)
        .Collection(p => p.Orders)
        .Query()
        .Where(o => o.Total > 10)
        .Load();

    foreach (var item in filteredOrders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

My suggestions:

Option 1:

```
using (var context = new SuperMarketContext())
{
    var product = context.Product
        .Include(p => p.Orders)
        .Where(p => p.Id == 5002)
        .First();

    var orders = product.Orders.Where(o => o.Total > 10).ToList();

    foreach (var item in orders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```
using (var context = new SuperMarketContext())
{
    var product = context.Product
        .Include(p => p.Orders)
        .Where(p => p.Id == 5002 && p.Orders.Where(t => t.Total > 10))
        .First();

    foreach (var item in product.Orders)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

Let me know if either of these work :)

Comment: The first option works! Thank you. The Second doesn't cause the p.Orders is a list of Order so it don't have Total property.

Comment: @EricFarias Hey glad it worked and thinking about the second one yeah I don't know why I thought that would work! I have updated to a solution that should work with the list